# Quickly generate numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to generate a sparse numpy ndarray by using the row vector, column vector, and value vector of each element.

For example, if I have

```
row_index=np.array([0,1,2])
column_index=np.array([2,1,0])
value=np.array([4,5,6])
```

Then I want a matrix

```
[0,0,4
0,5,0
6,0,0]
```

Is there a function in numpy that can do the similar thing like `scipy.sparse` by using `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])`? If not, is there a way to generate the matrix without `for` loops?  I want to speed up the code but
`scipy.sparse` is quite slow during the calculation, and the matrix I want is not so large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the matrix you want is not very large, it might be faster to just create a regular (non-sparse) ndarray. For example, you can use the following code to generate a dense matrix using only `numpy`:

```
row_index = np.array([0, 1, 2])
column_index = np.array([2, 1, 0])
values = np.array([4, 5, 6])

# numpy dense
M = np.zeros((np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
M[row_index, column_index] = values
```

On my machine, creating the matrix (the last two lines) take approximately 6.3 μs to run. I compared it to the following code which uses `scipy.sparse`:

```
# scipy sparse
M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((values, (row_index, column_index)),
                            shape=(np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
```

This takes approximately 80 μs to run. Because you asked for a method to create a sparse array, I changed the first implementation to the following code, so that the created ndarray is converted into a sparse array:

```
# numpy sparse
M = np.zeros((np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
M[row_index, column_index] = values
M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(M)
```

This takes approximately 82 μs to run. The bottleneck in this code is clearly the operation of creating a sparse matrix.

Note that the `scipy.sparse` method scales very well as function of matrix size, and eventually becomes the fastest for larger matrices (on my machine, starting from approximately 360×360). See the figure below for an indication of the speed of each method as function of matrix size, from a 10×10 matrix up to a 1000×1000 matrix. Some outliers in the figure are most likely due to other programs on my machine interfering. Furthermore, I am not sure of the technical details behind the 'jumps' in the numpy dense method at ~360×360 and ~510×510. I have also added the code I used to run this comparison so that you can run it on your own machine.

[image: Comparison of runtimes for various methods]

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

def generate_indices(num_values):
    row_index = np.arange(num_values)
    column_index = np.arange(num_values)[::-1]
    values = np.arange(num_values)
    
    return row_index, column_index, values

def numpy_dense(N, row_index, column_index, values):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for _ in range(N):
        M = np.zeros((np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
        M[row_index, column_index] = values
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    
    return (end - start) / N

def numpy_sparse(N, row_index, column_index, values):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for _ in range(N):
        M = np.zeros((np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
        M[row_index, column_index] = values
        M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(M)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    
    return (end - start) / N

def scipy_sparse(N, row_index, column_index, values):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for _ in range(N):
        M = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix((values, (row_index, column_index)),
                                    shape=(np.max(row_index) + 1, np.max(column_index) + 1))
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    
    return (end - start) / N

ns = np.arange(10, 1001, 10)  # matrix size to try with

runtimes_numpy_dense, runtimes_numpy_sparse, runtimes_scipy_sparse = [], [], []

for n in ns:
    print(n)
    indices = generate_indices(n)
    # number of iterations for timing
    # ideally, you want this to be as high as possible,
    # but I didn't want to wait very long for this plot
    N = 1000 if n < 500 else 100
    runtimes_numpy_dense.append(numpy_dense(N, *indices))
    runtimes_numpy_sparse.append(numpy_sparse(N, *indices))
    runtimes_scipy_sparse.append(scipy_sparse(N, *indices))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(ns, runtimes_numpy_dense, 'x-', markersize=4, label='numpy dense')
ax.plot(ns, runtimes_numpy_sparse, 'x-', markersize=4, label='numpy sparse')
ax.plot(ns, runtimes_scipy_sparse, 'x-', markersize=4, label='scipy sparse')

ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Matrix size')
ax.set_ylabel('Runtime (s)')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your (sparse) array in **coordinate** format, where you pass:

- values to be put at specified coordinates,
- row coordinates,
- column coordinates.

The code to do it can be:

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
arr = ss.coo_matrix((value, (row_index - 1, column_index - 1)))
```

Note that you created *row_index* and *column_index* with **1-based**
indexing in mind, whereas array indices are actually **0-based**,
so in the code above I subtracted *1* from your both coordinate arrays.

When you print `arr.toarray()`, you will get just what you wanted:

```
array([[0, 0, 4],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [6, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason that I don't want to create the array in this way is that it cost too much time. Even the process of converting ```sparse``` to ```np.array``` costs much longer than simply creating an array.